# Replacing an LCD screen in a laptop

Tags: laptop, resolution, lcd

So I just got my new laptop today -- HP Envy 15 -- and it turns out it's actually 1366 x 768 instead of the 1920 x 1080 I had originally thought it was... obviously I miss read :\

Anyways, I want to make this thing 1920 x 1080, I found a place where I can order an LCD screen. Just want to know:

A) If I replace the screen will it just work or are there some other components that might need to be upgraded in order for it to work...

B) Anyone know how to take out a screen when there's no visible screws in the front...

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to start by saying, this probably isn't possible. :)

a) You'll have to find a screen that's connector and power compatible with what's already in the notebook (not an easy task).  Then you'll have to hope the video sub-system (and it's drivers) support the higher resolution.

b) Usually you have to split the LCD shell in half (down the seam), if there's no screws then there are probably press-snap latches holding the halves together; don't be surprised if you break one or a few of them while separating.  Inside there will (probably) be the LCD panel in a frame (screwed to it) and that frame will be attached to the hinges.

The HP Envy 15 service manual is [here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01911053.pdf), disassembly starts at chapter 4, around page 39; use it to get proper disassembly order and to minimize damage when taking it apart.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You may have to replace the display cable that connects the LCD panel to the mainboard as well.

I remember coming across a thread where someone did the same thing you're trying to do, and they couldn't push their resolution past 1366 x 768 on a 1920 x 1080 panel. It turned out that the cable for the full HD panel was physically different (more wires for more bandwidth), and everything worked fine once the right cable was installed.

In any case, I highly recommend posting your question in the thread for your specific laptop in the notebookreview.com forums. You'll find a lot of folks there with specialized knowledge for your particular laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to disagree with the majority of the other answers and say this is possible, and I have done it quite a few times now.

There are quite a few different configurations - 20, 30 and 40 pin, then there are three usual subtypes where the connector is located in the top middle, bottom right or bottom left.

There are also some specialist ones for screens in ultra mobiles, ultra thin, long battery life etc.

I would first try plugging your laptop in to a HD TV if you have one, or just any 1080p monitor. If you can see output on it, your graphics chip is powerful enough for 1080p output. (may have problems if you want dual screens with another one though - can't rule it out).

If it is compatible, just pick a screen that has the cables in the correct place and type, then connect it.

Laptop LCD panels are very similar to computer screens in the fact that the monitor panel can "tell" the machine what modes it supports, and depending on your driver, the moment you configure it, it may go straight to 1080p.

FYI, this will obviously invalidate your warranty and not be *that* cheap, you may want to see if there is a 1080p laptop out the box that is better suited for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the screen, I would recommend the sidekick site iFixit as a place to start, although it is a bit Apple-centric at the moment, there are discussion forums that would probably give you useful advice.

To increase the resolution, you would certainly need to replace the LCD driver hardware - the chip that generates the signals to update the screen. I fear that this is not going to be possible as this chip will be paired with the other components on the motherboard and all the other chips will expect the LCD driver to work in a specific way.